# How bundler in rails 3 manages gem dependencies?

Tags: bundler

I am new in rails 3 and need to know how rails manage gem dependencies in rails 3 also i need to know how it is differ from older rails version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there have been any changes to the basic workflow. It is enabled by default in Rails 3 whereas you had to set it up manually in 2.3.x.

Basically, bundler takes the requirements set out in your Gemfile (gem name, minimum version, exact version etc), and it works out a set of gems that meet those requirements. It records the exact versions in Gemfile.lock, and takes responsiblity for 'requiring' any gems you need in your application.

It's worth reading the manual, especially with respect to the various deployment options.

See [gembundler.com](http://gembundler.com/rails3.html) for a summary of how to use it in Rails 3.

Comment: Thanks Henry it's helpful for me